# what is the difference between Java Persistence API(JPA) and Java Transaction API. (JTA)

Tags: jpa, java-ee-7, jta

What is the main difference between Java Persistence API(JPA) and the Java Transaction API(JTA). I read these two terms in Java EE 7 .

Comment: they are two completely different API's.  The only thing they have in common is they are part of Java EE.

Comment: `and the Java Transaction API(JTA)`

You wrote Java Persistence API twice.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is an object-relational mapping tool that allows mapping between entity objects which are classes with their corresponding tables and their attributes in the database. Whereas JTA is a tool that allows you to make multiple transactions in multiple schema.